# Are there classes which cannot be specified by language?

Tags: set-theory

> In set theory and its applications throughout mathematics, a class is
>   a collection of sets (or sometimes other mathematical objects) that
>   can be unambiguously defined by a property that all its members share. - ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28set_theory%29))

I am curious whether there exists a class which cannot be specified by language.  There's some intuitive sense that there should always be a way to define them by writing down the shared property, but that seems to limit the cardinality of "the class of all classes."

Obviously this is not a trivial question to ask, because the definition of "class" itself is not formally defined in all set theories, and I am interested in the possibility that the different theories admit different answers (for example, I have read that Von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory does not admit "the class of all classes," so the intuition already shows cracks).

I choose to scope "language" to be its mathematically defined meaning: a language consists of the set of words, Σ*, which consist of a finite series of symbols called letters (which are, themselves, a set).  If it proves interesting, I will also admit an infinite series of letters.  By this definition, "the class of all classes" is a a valid sentence (or "word," if I am to be consistent with my notation), although it does not technically have to identify a class. (All classes must be uniquely specified, but all specifications need specify classes)

I choose to scope "specify" to be a mapping from a "word" to a class which uniquely identifies said class.  This appears to be either related or identical to the Representation function in NBG, so feel free to use that if it proves convenient.

My intuition suggests that there are classes which cannot be specified by language because there are "too few" elements in a set.  However, I am merely a programmer who has read Godel-Escher-Bach and too many Wikipedia pages, so I will also accept answers which suggest that I am not asking for the right thing, and encourage me in a good direction.

Comment: See [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/44129/75) to a similar question on MO.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you.  I hadn't come across that answer when I looked for them.  I'll have to let it digest and determine if it answers my question, or if it helps me identify further questions.

Comment: The question linked by @EricWofsey does correctly answer the question asked here.  If it also leads OP to identify further questions that is great.